# SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] with compile and speed issues

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, memory

I am trying to run a code that gives out a matrix but, I seem to encounter some memory issues while trying to run it. The code is:

```
rm[{mx_, mz_}] := {0.048 mx (1 - 1/(2 Abs[mx])), 0.048 mz (1 - 1/(2 Abs[mz]))}; 

ListOfm = Outer[{#1, #2} &, DeleteCases[ Range[-128/2, 128/2, 1], 0, Infinity], DeleteCases[ Range[-128/2, 128/2, 1], 0, Infinity], 1];
ListOfrm = Map[rm, ListOfm, {2}];
              
rn[{nx_, nz_}] := {0.016 nx (1 - 1/(2 Abs[nx])), 0.016 nz (1 - 1/(2 Abs[nz]))} 

ListOfn = Outer[{#1, #2} &, DeleteCases[Range[-384/2, 384/2, 1], 0, Infinity], DeleteCases[Range[-384/2, 384/2, 1], 0, Infinity], 1];
ListOfrn = Map[rn, ListOfn, {2}];



Fun = Compile[{{rm, _Real, 1}, {rn, _Real, 1}},
              
      Exp[-((Compile`GetElement[rm, 1] - Compile`GetElement[rn, 1])^2/2 + 
            (Compile`GetElement[rm, 2] - Compile`GetElement[rn, 2])^2/2)], 

      CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

 With[{Fun= Fun},
      Mat = Compile[{{rm, _Real, 2}, {rn, _Real, 2}},
                              
                    Table[Table[Fun[Compile`GetElement[rm, i], Compile`GetElement[rn, j]],
                               {i, 1, Length[rm]}], {j, 1, Length[rn]}], 
                                                    
            CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
            RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];
```

When I input

```
Mat[Flatten[ListOfrm, 1], Flatten[ListOfrn, 1]]
```

I receive an error that

> General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.
>
> Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[[Ellipsis], _SystemException].
>
> Out[124]= SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]

However if I use lower number of elements (`64` and `192`) like:

```
ListOfm = Outer[{#1, #2} &, DeleteCases[ Range[-64/2, 64/2, 1], 0, Infinity], DeleteCases[ Range[-64/2, 64/2, 1], 0, Infinity], 1];
ListOfrm = Map[rm, ListOfm, {2}];

 ListOfn = Outer[{#1, #2} &, DeleteCases[Range[-192/2, 192/2, 1], 0, Infinity], DeleteCases[Range[-192/2, 192/2, 1], 0, Infinity], 1];
ListOfrn = Map[rn, ListOfn, {2}];
```

the error does not show up but the computation takes a lot of time.

I want to use higher number of elements with a good time efficiency. How can I deal with this error and speed up my code?.

Comment: The $116384 \times 147456$ matrix that you try to assemble would require more than 147 GB of RAM. So either you have to buy a cosiderable amount of RAM or you have to think about another way to accomplish your actual goal.

Comment: If I give a minimum value below which the function evaluates to zero then can I make a sparse matrix out of it?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice that your code doesn't run in parallel? Compiled parallelization works by using the *Listability* of Mathematica and then your code is run in parallel. To give a short pseudo-example: **Instead** of doing this

```
f[list_] := Table[DoSomething[element], {element, list}];
f[myList]
```

you will implement it like that

```
f[element_] := DoSomething[element];
f[myList]
```

So you define your compiled function for *one element you want to process* and you do not iterate over the list of elements yourself. To make it perfectly clear, look at this minimal example

```
fc = Compile[{{elm, _Real, 0}}, elm + 1, 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
fc[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
(* {2., 3., 4., 5.} *)
```

If you understand this then you will see why your code does not run in parallel. Let us fix this by using a definition of fun that works and replaces your nested `Table` in `Mat`

```
funParallel = Compile[{{rm, _Real, 2}, {rn, _Real, 1}},
   Table[
    Exp[-((Compile`GetElement[rm, i, 1] - 
            Compile`GetElement[rn, 1])^2/
         2 + (Compile`GetElement[rm, i, 2] - 
            Compile`GetElement[rn, 2])^2/2)],
    {i, Length[rm]}
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

Look carefully at the type-specs in my `Compile` call. We will take the whole matrix for `rm`, but only a single point for `rn`. That means, inside the body, we actively iterate over the `rm`, but when we provide a matrix of `rn`, then this will happen in parallel.

I have made some tests with smaller values and the result is the same as for your `Mat` call. However, it runs faster and doesn't use so much memory on my machine

```
r2 = funParallel[Flatten[ListOfm, 1], Flatten[ListOfn, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

takes about 20 seconds here and the result is 18GB large. I'm not sure I missed something, because my result has dimensions {16384, 147456} which is substantially smaller than what Henrik said, but maybe he only included an additional 1 accidentally.

Comment: The $1$ was only a typo. My real fault was to forget that to divide by $8$, so the estimated size is 147 GigaBit which is 18 GigaByte. Silly me. Good job btw (+1).